# Сравнить массив строк и массив объектов и добавить недостающие значения в массив объектов

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, подскажите, плиз, что у меня не так с кодом.
Есть два массива:

```
let template = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']; 
let features = [{ 
    name: 'a', 
    value: 111 
  }, 
  { 
    name: 'c', 
    value: 222 
  } 
];
```

Мне нужно получить обновленный features такого вида:

```
let features = [{ 
        name: 'a', 
        value: 111 
      },
      { 
        name: 'b', 
        value: 'DEFAULT'
      },
      { 
        name: 'c', 
        value: 222 
      },
      { 
        name: 'd', 
        value: 'DEFAULT'
      },
      { 
        name: 'e', 
        value: 'DEFAULT'
      } 
    ];
```

Т.е. в массив features нужно добавить недостающие обьекты с value 'DEFAULT' для имен, которых нет в массиве template.
Мой вариант не работает, ставила brake  для выхода из циклов, но не помогает ((

```
let result = []; 

for (let s of template) { 
  for (let z of features) { 
     if (s === z.name) { 
      result.push(z) 
     } else { 
      result.push({ 
        name: s, 
        value: 'DEFAUILT' 
      }) 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: ой, да, сори, поправила

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас дублируются добавляемые объекты, потому что вы пушите при несовпадении любого объекта с текущим шаблоном, а нужно только если ни один объект не совпал с шаблоном. Попробуйте так:

```js
let template = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let features = [{
    name: 'a',
    value: 111
  },
  {
    name: 'c',
    value: 222
  }
];

let result = [];

for (let s of template) {
  const found = features.find(feature => feature.name === s);
  result.push(found || { name: s, value: 'DEFAUILT' });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: аа, поняла, спасибо большое)